# In dictionary of python how to print value of a key if it have multiple values stored?

Tags: python

I have defined a dict like below:

```
a = { "b" : [20,40,45]}
```

The command `a['b']` will print all the values like below

```
[20, 40, 45]
```

. I just want one value. How do I get the single value of b in values?
What I have to do to print lets say 45?

what can I do now is below:

```
d = a['b']
print d[2]
```

How to do it in one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple!

```
print a['b'][2]
```

Don't you love python ;)?

The logic behind this is: We are getting the 3rd item from the list `a['b']`. Which would be `[20, 40, 45][2]`. Hence, 45 :)

Comment: oh yes! the brackets. what I did was print a['b'](2). Thank you.

Comment: If you always want the last element use `print a['b'][-1]`.